# CSS Table Layout - filling second row squishes prior

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a page with a row of data followed by hide-able help text. Though the current layout is sort of like a table, the data itself is not, and I'm trying to avoid using HTML tables. I have a few sets of data elements that I would like to align along columns, each followed by some help text that I want to take up the whole width available to it.

The trouble is, I can't seem to get the help text to take up the full width without messing up the column alignment of the previous rows. I can get the columns I want using using `table-layout: fixed` in the CSS, but the help text will then only get one column's worth of width. To get the help text to span the parent's width, I use `table-layout: auto` and wrap the contents of the help text div in one element, giving it `display: table-cell`. That works, but messes up the preceding columns of data.

What is a semantically appropriate way to display this data, but still get the layout I want?

## Squashed help text

https://jsfiddle.net/c1rq53zv/2/

### HTML

```
<section class="summary">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="title"><span class="clickableTitle">A title</span></div>
        <div class="data">Some Data</div>
        <div class="actions"><a href="http://google.com">A link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="helpText">
        <strong>A bold help title</strong>
        <ul>
            <li>A list item with exceptionally long text, which is wherein we discover our problem</li>
            <li>Some other list item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <div class="title"><span class="clickableTitle">Another title</span></div>
        <div class="data">Some other Data</div>
        <div class="actions"><a href="http://google.com">A link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="helpText">This div just has some straight text in it. The text goes on a bit, which will also cause the problem, regardless of whether I wrap it in a p tag or any similar wrapping markup.</div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.summary {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.info{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.title{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.data{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 25%;
    text-align:right;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.actions{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 30%;
    text-align:right;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.helpText{
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

### Javascript to show/hide the help text

```
$(function() {
    $(".clickableTitle").click(function() {
        hideHelpText(this)
    });
});

function hideHelpText(helpTitle) {
    console.log("I clicked it");
    var parentSection = $(helpTitle).closest('.info');
    var helpText = parentSection.next('.helpText');
    helpText.toggle();
}
```

## Messed up columns

The javascript is unchanged. If you hide all the help text, then the columns revert to what I'd like them to look like.
https://jsfiddle.net/o13r9jke/

### HTML

Largely the same, but I added some child element wrappers so that I could give them a table-cell display.

```
<section class="summary">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="title"><span class="clickableTitle">A title</span></div>
        <div class="data">Some Data</div>
        <div class="actions"><a href="http://google.com">A link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="helpText">
        <div>
        <strong>A bold help title</strong>
        <ul>
            <li>A list item with exceptionally long text, which is wherein we discover our problem</li>
            <li>Some other list item</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <div class="title"><span class="clickableTitle">Another title</span></div>
        <div class="data">Some other Data</div>
        <div class="actions"><a href="http://google.com">A link</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="helpText"><p>This div just has some straight text in it. The text goes on a bit, which will also cause the problem, regardless of whether I wrap it in a p tag or any similar wrapping markup.</p></div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.summary {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: initial;
}
.info{
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.title{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
}
.data{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 25%;
    text-align:right;
}
.actions{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 30%;
    text-align:right;
}
.helpText{
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.helpText > * {display: table-cell; width: 100%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, as it turns out, was to simply stop trying to treat the helpText as part of a table at all! As with so many other things, it helped to back out all the CSS class changes and start over from scratch.

https://jsfiddle.net/u9nucym6/

```
.info{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.title{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 45%;
    max-width: 45%;
}
.data{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 25%;
    text-align:right;
}
.actions{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 30%;
    text-align:right;
}
.helpText{ width: 100%; }
```